# Update database by getting the sum of a value in a specific column in listview and the value in my database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, xampp

In my database i have a table named [productlist] and inside it are (Name),(Stock) (Brand),(Size)

i have a listview like this:

```
|Qty| Name  | Brand  | Size  |
| 2 | Name 1| Brand 1| Size 1|
| 2 | Name 2| Brand 2| Size 2|
```

what i want to happen is when i click save button
the value of "Qty" in my listview will be added to the value of "Stock" in my database

(value of Qty in my listview) + (current value of Stock in my productlist table) = (Stock in my productlist table)

i dont how to start so i tried this code but it didnt work:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click


Dim MyConnection As New MySqlConnection
Dim MyTransaction As MySqlTransaction = Nothing

MyConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=empiredb;Uid=root;"

    MyConnection.Open()
    MyTransaction = MyConnection.BeginTransaction


For Each item As ListViewItem In lvwProductPurchases.Items



Dim SQL As String = "update productlist set [Stock] = [Stock] + @0 where Name = @1 and Brand = @2 and Size = @3"

Dim CMD4 As New MySqlCommand

            CMD4.Connection = MyConnection
            CMD4.Transaction = MyTransaction
            CMD4.CommandText = SQL
            CMD4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", item.Text)
            CMD4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", item.SubItems(1).Text)
            CMD4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", item.SubItems(2).Text)
            CMD4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", item.SubItems(3).Text)
            CMD4.ExecuteNonQuery()
            CMD4.Dispose()
Next
  MsgBox("updated")
'try and catch i will put transactionrollback
End sub
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Stock] = [Stock] + '2' where Name = 'kahoy' and Brand = 'Brand 1' and Size = 'm' at line 1

Comment: Can you tell us which line of code has the problem?  Otherwise, the only way to help you would be for a VBA guru to read this, or for someone to test your actual code locally.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Stock] = [Stock] + '2' where Name = 'kahoy' and Brand = 'Brand 1' and Size = 'm' at line 1

Comment: i don't know how to get the value of stock in my database and put it in my update query so that i can get the sum of both values

Comment: I gave an answer below, which should fix at least one of your problems.  I'm happy to iterate with you until we get your code working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done much work with VB.net, but I do see one problem with your MySQL query.  In MySQL, placing brackets around column names to escape/refer to them is not valid syntax.  It is valid in SQL Server, Access, and maybe a few other databases.  I propose using the following syntax for your query:

```
Dim SQL As String = "UPDATE productlist SET Stock = Stock + @0 " _
                    "WHERE Name = @1 AND Brand = @2 AND Size = @3"
```

Comment: OMG u got it!  and its that simple!? thank you very much! i hope you will be able to see my new question next time i have a problem. thank you very much!

Comment: @sid Happy to help you.  That the column name issue was the only major problem indicates that you generally wrote good code.  Keep up that effort.